# How do i write a function with a counter inside?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

First week coding please be kind.
I need to get 4 inputs from the user and if 2 of those are `-100` I need function to say you fail.

I need to implement the `function here` and probably add a counter inside but I dont know how.

Code looks something like this

```
cout << "What are the grades of your 4 take-home exams? ";
    cin >>th1>>th2>>th3>>th4;
function here
```

Comment: Define counter as static inside the function.

Comment: You may want to read this: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: @FarhadSarvari: I would **not** recommend using a `static` variable in this case.

Comment: I strongly suggest talking with your teaching staff, but in the absence of that: how would you do this without a function? Do that first, then when it's working, create a function, cut-paste the relevant code into the new function, and make sure you're passing the right variables and returning the right type of variable.

Comment: `int ex[4] = { th1, th2, th3, th4 }; int failCount = std::count_if(std::cbegin(ex), std::cend(ex), [] (int ele) { return ele == -100; }); if(failCount >= 2) std::cout << "fail"; else std::cout << "pass";`

Comment: @George: I doubt that you can expect a first-week student to understand lambda expressions. :-)

Comment: Is my assumption correct that you have not yet learnt what arrays are? And have you learnt `for`/`while` loops yet?

Answer (score 5):

> I need to get 4 inputs from the user

```
cin >>th1>>th2>>th3>>th4;
```

Looks like this is correct.

> if 2 of those are -100

### 1. Conditionals

The answer is in your question itself. Focus on the word **`if`**.

Programming languages have all sorts of different ways to check things, to check *if* something is equal to something else, or *if* something is *less than* something else, run a certain piece of code. We call these **conditions**. If a certain condition is **true**, do something, **else**, do something different. Example:

```
int x = 0;
cin >> x; // take input from user
if (x > 20)
{
   cout << "x is greater than 20";
}
else 
{
   cout << "x is less than 20";
}
```

Moreover, You can even check two variables at the same time!!

```
int x = 1;
int y = 2;
if (x == 1 && y == 2)
   cout << "X is 1, and y is 2";
else
   //print something else
```

### Functions

Functions are a way to put some code in a block, that you can reuse whenever you want. Think of this like, suppose you are making a cake and you need a certain syrup for it. Now if you want, you can make that syrup every time from zero, or you can just make a lot of syrup, and use it every time when you want to make a cake. It's definitely a bad example, but you get the point.

Lets make a small function. This function will take an `int` as parameter and check if that parameter is equal to 100 or not. If it is equal to 100, we will *`return`* a value: `1` to the caller. Otherwise we will return a value: `0`:

```
int checkIfHundredOrNot(int value)
{
    if (value == 100)
       return 1;
    else
       return 0;
}

//caller
int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    cin >> x;
    int result = checkIfHundredOrNot(int value);
    cout << "Result is: " << result;
    return 0;
}
```

With this information, try and solve your problem. It should be fairly straightforward. If you find anything difficult, google it. You will find all your answers there. Specifically google this:

- What is a function parameter in C++?
- What is return value in C++?
- What is a function in C++?
- Why do we use functions in C++?
- What are operators in C++?
- What are comparison operators in C++?
- Is there a difference between `=` and `==`?

Then read them carefully and write down every piece of code with your own hands and repeat till you understand it.

Comment: `checkIfHundredOrNot` should return `bool`, not `int`.

Comment: Of course, but just tried to keep it very simple using only one data type. `int`

Answer (score 0):

So I m kind of a noob myself but I ll give it a shot.
I would recommand taking a look at my solution and try doing yours in a "you" way since there are manny more paths to achieving the right answer.
If you are really specific about only having 4 inputs you can try this:

```
bool isFail(int a, int b, int c, int d) {

int counter = 0;
if (a == -100) {
    counter++;
}
if (b == -100) {
    counter++;
}
if (c == -100) {
    counter++;
}
if (d == -100) {
    counter++;
}

if (counter >= 2) {
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

}

The function basically takes 4 ints and checks each one of them against -100. If they turn out to be -100 the counter increases by 1.
Afterwards we simply check if the counter is equal to or bigger than two and if so we return a true value since it is failed (tow or more inputs are -100). If not, we simply return a false.

In your main function you can simply initialize your variables, input them and simply do a function call that you can compare against another "true" value. If the result is positive you print out a fail message.

```
int a, b, c, d;
std::cin >> a >> b >> c >> d;

if (isFail(a, b, c, d) == true) {
    std::cout << "Fail!" << std::endl;;
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Passed!" << std::endl;
}
```

Best regards!